# How to check that a file is being streamed and not downloaded?

Tags: nginx, audio-streaming, jwplayer

Abstract: There is a page with a player that loads audio file and plays it. The player used on the web page is [jwplayer](http://jwplayer.com). I need to find a way to determine if the audio file is being streamed to the player or not.

Background: In my research I found that if I use nginx header like X-Accel-Redirect - the file will be streamed. I have setup the web server with nginx + apache combination (nginx is reverse proxy for apache), after that I pointed jwplayer to the mp3 file - and it is working. I mean I am able to click anywhere on the audio timeline and it immediately starts playing sound. But, since I didn't set that header yet, and adding the fact that player already works - that's why I need to check my question and know for sure.

Some of my own thoughts: JwPlayer itself supports some kind of bufferring, so I have no idea whether it just downloads the mp3 file I am testing this functions on, or it receives the stream and plays it out.

Is there a way to check and know for sure? The only idea about all of this I have is to check access logs, but I don't know what to look for, or if I need a special format for the logs to see those requried data.

While I was researching the issue I got some weird download related topics and something about HTTP headers with "Ranges" in them, but I am not sure that it relates to the streaming or not.

Please advice.

Answer (score 5):

From the point of view of the server, there is no difference between download and streaming. A server just send bits. What happens to those bits later is unknown. What you need is a player that sends reports to back to the server or a loging service such as mixpanel.